# How to clear temporary memory usage programmtically as part of a call to MSSQL via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.6, pyodbc

I've set up a process that connects to MSSQL, runs an SP, pulls back its summary output via pandas and prints to screen as well as emailing me a copy of output.

This all works as expected, but each of the last two evenings I've run it, I've gotten notice that some part of the process has filled the tempdb on the server I've connected to.

I've included a request to close the connection as part of the python script, but this continues to happen which makes me think it's something intrinsic to either pyodbc or running SQL from within python.  The SP itself is not particularly memory hungry (running the SP within SSMS produces no such issue), so this isn't a SQL-specific issue.

Does pyodbc have some kind of memory release method or is there some other way I can run this without needing to make some manual adjustment to avoid filling the tempdb?

Sample code below for reference:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('''
                      TRUSTED_CONNECTION=Yes;
                      DRIVER={SQL Server};
                      SERVER={myServer};
                      DATABASE=myDB;''')


r = pd.read_sql("exec [mySP]",conn)  
print(r.to_string(index=False))

conn.close()
```

Comment: Recently, I had to find a way to release the memory accumulated from a python program that was looping through a data set. I was able to reduce the amount of memory accumulated during each iteration via explicit garbage collection. However, this was not enough. My final solution was to create a wrapper that calls my python program as a parallel processes. Thus, when the program finishes the memory accumulated by that process is released when the process exits. If this sounds like it would help I would gladly write up a more detailed answer.

Comment: Be aware that by default pyodbc opens connections as `autocommit=False` (as per the Python DB-API spec) so your entire SP may be running inside a transaction. You might try adding `, autocommit=True` to your [.connect](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) call to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run a query from the pyodbc connection and see if it gives you the same result, you can run a simple query something like this:

```
  conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                          "Server=myServer;"
                          "Database=myDB;"
                          "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''
    SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table.db WHERE COLUMN.2 = 'something' ''' )
    for row in cursor:
        # print(row[1:3])
            row1 = row[2]
            return row1

    conn.close()
```